# Exponent rules under a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a,b\in G$ where $<G,\odot >$ is a group. Then, what is $(a \odot b)^3$?

I understand the basic exponent rules like $(a^2)^3=(a^3)^2$ and $(a\odot b)^{-1}=b^{-1} \odot a^{-1}$.
However, would $(a \odot b)^3 = b^3 \odot a^3$ or $(a^3\odot b^3)$ or would I have to foil? If I have to foil, how would I do so?

Sorry if this is a simple question, I couldn't find any examples anywhere to satisfy by curiousity.

Comment: No, $(ab)^3=b^3a^3$ need not be true. $(ab)^3$ is just $ababab$. What do you mean by "foil"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde FOIL is a mnemonic for expanding the product $(a + b)(c + d)$: First, Outside, Inside, Last.

Comment: "F.O.I.L" has absolutely no meaning in a group. It refers to the act of applying the distributive law in a ring, and relates two operations. In a group, you only have one, and it usually does not distribute over itself.  Such are the perils of the "apply random technique to problem" approach to mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we just write group multiplication as juxtaposition, so that $ab := a \odot b$, then $(ab)^3 = ababab$, and for general groups there's nothing more we can say.

If the group $G$ is abelian, so that $ab = ba$ for all $a, b \in G$, then $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2$. Conversely, if this identity holds for all $a, b$, then expanding gives $abab = a^2 b^2$, and multiplying on the left by $a^{-1}$ and on the right by $b^{-1}$ gives $ba = ab$, so this condition is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.

Comment: Sorry I was just talking under general groups, not group multiplication. So just to re-clarify, there is no simplification more than $(a\star b)^3$? Does that second paragraph work for any general group or just group multiplication?

Comment: In the context of group theory, the term _multiplication_ often (as it does in my answer) refers to any group operation.